# PWA install prompt in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, progressive-web-apps

Is there any possibility to show "Add To Home Screen" prompt when user visits our application ? Currently, users need to click 3 dot menu button and then "Add to home screen".

Secondly, In iPhone, safari takes the screen shot of the page when we hit "add to home screen" button and use as icon. Can't we use custom icon in iPhone ?

Regards
T

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in [Add to Home Screen](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#show_the_prompt)

> **Show the prompt**
>
> To show the add to home screen prompt, call prompt() on the saved event from within a user gesture. It will show a
> modal dialog, asking the user to to add your app to their home screen.
>
> Then, listen for the promise returned by the userChoice property. The
> promise returns an object with an outcome property after the prompt
> has shown and the user has responded to it.
>
> **Updating your app's icon and name**
>
> If you change any of the properties in your manifest, those changes
> will be reflected to the user after they've run your app again.
>
> Tip: Icons may be cached, so it may be helpful to change the filenames
> when updating icons or other graphics.